# Which action should take newly created keyframes?

Tags: animation, dopesheet

I created a new action named BladeAction and keyframed the influence slider of a *Shape Key* I couldn't use the action in the *Logic Nodes / Action Actuator*. Then I examined the action in the *NLA* and *Action Editor* it looks like that:

[image]

A KeyAction strip has been created by Blender and is not accessible from the *Action Editor* the BladeAction has no keyframes and cannot be frozen (snowflake icon). I can use the KeyAction from *Action Actuator* but I'm somewhat confused why this behaves like that.

Why are no keyframes in the *Action* created by me? Why does *Blender* create an Action Strip* which cannot be edited?

[.blend] is already linked here: [Can gravity be disabled for a single object in the BGE?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8737/can-gravity-be-disabled-for-a-single-object-in-the-bge)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that only *Keying Sets* like location, rotation accessible from the *Keyframe Menu* are stored in the currently active *Action*.

For each other property like influence slider values, colors, transparency etc. an F-curve associated to the object is created and holds the keyframes and some kind of virtual *Action Strip* is added to the *NLA Editor*.