# How to get the normal of the face which was hit in a collision?

Tags: game-engine, physics

I would like to make an object stay at the height (Z) and velocity it was created at (it's created from another object with an *Edit object* actuator). Ideally it should be allowed to bounce up/down, but not allowed to fall (think very slow light ray).
I would like this object to bounce off only certain objects.

I couldn't get an object to do this with collision groups + physics (it seems like it should be possible though, so if it is, please say so :)

I thought I would try and handle bouncing with python, however I can't figure out how to get the normal of the face it hits on collision (I'm using a collision sensor with a property)

How can I get an object to behave like this?

[**Blendfile**](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/29386)

Comment: Could you add your blend, I would try to add the ray sensor. But this might take a few days.

Comment: @stacker Added .blend

Comment: So far I tried to check the ray sensor independently from the collision sensor it sometime hit, made sure that the orientation (+Y) is taken into account (therefore I messed up the bullet obj). One issue is was the filter configured at the sensors you need a material or property called wall. I will give it another try, http://pasteall.org/blend/29396 for relfection using the normal see: http://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-177557.html

Comment: @stacker Thanks. I do have walls (with a wall property), but they are set to wireframe (and are invisible when the BGE is run). They are on layer 3

Comment: In a simpler setup I noticed that a collision is only detected when the Physics Type of the object is set to sensor. Collision bounds are also required (but you have set them as I remember)

Comment: @stacker It's still behaving intermittently, with sensor set on the bullet object and collision bounds on the bullet and wall objects.. I don't get why the ray sensor isn't triggering :/

Comment: I gave up on that, did you achieve something? My solution for a similar issue was http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8737/can-gravity-be-disabled-for-a-single-object-in-the-bge but this object and collisions are controled by the physics engine.

Comment: @stacker Sorry, I kind of stopped working on this project for a while.. I did see that [a bug with the ray sensor axes was recently fixed](https://developer.blender.org/rB8f30414c29bc62447bc6664d9395778cae027133), so I might have another look soon.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use a [ray sensor](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_60_6/bge.types.html#bge.types.KX_RaySensor):

```
c = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
ray = c.sensors["raySensorName"]

if ray.positive:
    pos_vec = Vector(ray.hitPosition)
    normal_vec = Vector(ray.hitNormal)
```

Comment: Could you explain more? I'm rather new to the GE.. How would this work with collisions? Fire a ray on collision? How would I do that? Thanks :)

Comment: I guess you add a ray sensor as well and when the a collision happens you can get the position and normal of the colliding face (the ray sensor casts rays on a selected axis and checks whether it hits something). I haven't used the ray sensor yet, this tutorial has a .blend file with scripts using the ray-sensor attached: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AXqXqLmsa1o